ILRepack and ProjectReference
There are tons of examples how to merge 3rd party libraries. But what about situation where libraries: A, B(depend on A) and C (depend on A) are projects in the same solution.
And the goal is to make B containing A just to get rid of one additional binary in the delivery? But keep A still be generated separatly for another purpose...
Merging process as I did, is finished without errors, but there is still dependency on A.dll and crash by using B, because of missed A.
Do I some global mistake? Is this scenario not considered?
Tryed ILRepack.MSBuild.Task and ILRepack.Lib.MSBuild.Task.
The environment is net45 VS2017
Update: Found out that it was caused by using DllExport. It producing three dlls: one "AnyCPU", whitch was happily merged and x86/x64 which I really need. But these weren't affected by merge.

Could you please [edit] your post to contain a [mre] of your merging process and code?
